# GPIO listener on Compute module 3 Pi4J

Tags: gpio, pi4j, compute-module-3

I am doing a project where I use a compute module 3 with Raspbian Jessi Lite, Java with the Pi4J lib version 1.2-SNAPSHOT. I'm trying to implement a GpioPinListenerDigital on the GPIO_23 like so:

```
  public class SwitchAm {

    final GpioController gpio = GpioFactory.getInstance();
    final GpioPinDigitalInput myButton = gpio.provisionDigitalInputPin(RCMPin.GPIO_23, PinPullResistance.PULL_DOWN);



    SwitchAm(){

        myButton.setMode(PinMode.DIGITAL_INPUT);
        myButton.setShutdownOptions(true);

        GpioPinListenerDigital listener  = new GpioPinListenerDigital() {
            @Override
            public void handleGpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent(GpioPinDigitalStateChangeEvent event) {
                // display pin state on console
                System.out.println(" --> GPIO PIN STATE CHANGE: " + event.getPin() + " = " + event.getState());
            }
        };

        myButton.addListener(listener);
    }

    boolean getState()
    {
        return myButton.isHigh();
    }
}
```

Sadly the listener is never called, but I can still get the correct GPIO state with getState.

I also tested the exact same code on a raspberry pi 3 model b and the listener is working perfectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps Pi4J doesn't work with the compute module?  I suggest you raise an issue on the Pi4J site at https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j/issues/ after checking the FAQ.

Comment: The code I took was from the compute module section from http://pi4j.com so I hope it should work, maybe not for compute module 3.